# Use NavigateAsync in Prism.Forms with an already existant ViewModel

Tags: xamarin, mvvm, xamarin.forms, prism, viewmodellocator

**Scenario:** I have view, view model and model for `PickList` and `PickLine`. The `PickListViewModel` contains an `ObservableCollection<PickLineViewModel>` and the `PickList` model contains a `List<PickLine>`. My `PickList` page contains a `ListView` which is bound to the `ObservableCollection<PickLineViewModel>` and if a line is tapped `NavigateAsync` is called to navigate to the tapped PickLine.

Normally, when I call `NavigateAsync` Prism navigates to the page, locates the view model, creates an instance of it and binds this instance to the view. But in this case the view model instance that should be bound to the page is already existant (as an element of my `ObservableCollection`) and I don't want the Prism ViewModelLocator to create a new instance, due to the fact that it then would have to get data from web service and I try to keep the number of web service calls as low as possible.

Also I can't use models in the `ObservableCollection` because the view model contains properties which are only used for UI purposes so these properties should definitely not be part of the model, but the UI properties I'm talking about are needed in the `PickList` page and in the `PickLine` page.

Tl;dr: Is there any way in Prism.Forms to provide a view model instance 
on navigating to a page that will than be bound to it?

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that you are confusing what a Model is and what a ViewModel is. In this case what you should have is:

- PickLine (Model)
- PickLineView (View)
- PickLineViewModel (ViewModel)
- PickLineListView (View)
- PickLineListViewModel (ViewModel)

  - Containing your ObservableCollection of `PickLine` not PickLineViewModel

Without seeing your precise code, I'm going to take a guess from experience here that your code probably looks something like the following in principal:

```
public ObservableCollection<PickLineViewModel> Items { get; set; }
public DelegateCommand<PickLineViewModel> ItemTappedCommand { get; }
public void OnNavigatedTo(INavigationAware parameters)
{
    var picks = _dataService.GetPickLines();
    Items = new ObservableCollection<PickLineViewModel>(
              picks.Select(x => new PickLineViewModel
              {
                  Model = x,
                  ItemTappedCommand = ItemTappedCommand
              });
}
```

I see code like the above a lot from people who confuse the difference between a Model and ViewModel, and often from people who don't understand how to properly bind back to the ViewModel from something like a Cell in a ListView.

What you should have instead is code that is more like:

```
public ObservableCollection<PickLine> Items { get; set; }
public DelegateCommand<PickLine> ItemTappedCommand { get; }
public void OnNavigatedTo(INavigationAware parameters)
{
    var picks = _dataService.GetPickLines();
    Items = new ObservableCollection<PickLine>(picks);
}
```

Comment: I know what you mean and I tried it this way, but I have a property that is only used in UI. I try to provide an example: I have a property that's named `IsBooked` which determines if data has been entered for a specific PickLine. This property is only relevant to the UI, because if I select a PickLine to capture data, enter a quantity for example and than go back to the PickList, `IsBooked` for this line should be set to `true` and the PickListPage should set the lines color to a different color (using a bool2color converter). So I need view models because models should not contain UI stuff.

Comment: That's fine...What you're binding to is still a Model not a ViewModel... when you navigate you're passing a Model not a ViewModel... when you name things ViewModel and it's a Model you'll only serve to confuse yourself and anyone who touches the code.

Comment: But as I said the `IsBooked` property would only be used in the UI to determine if data was already entered for a `PickLine`. Or do you mean I should have a model that contains the `IsBooked` property and that is only used in my UI (Xamarin) project and if it gets sent to the server (where the `IsBooked` property is completely irrelevant) I "convert" the model of the UI project to a model for the server. So, I think, a bit like having a business object and a data transfer object or something. Would this be the proper way?

Answer (score 0):

> Is there any way in Prism.Forms to provide a view model instance on navigating to a page that will than be bound to it?

No, as far as I know, Prism Forms does not provide view model-first navigation (as opposed to Prism on WPF which does).

You should be able to work around this, though, by passing your existing view model as parameter and making the `ViewModelLocator`-created view model an "empty shell" that redirects everything to the actual view model.

Comment: This sounds like something, that could work. Could you maybe provide a short sample code or something for how to modify the ViewModelLocator to work like you wrote (meaning getting the ViewModel instance from the NavigationParameters and binding this instance to the page instance)?

Comment: Let me rephrase: the page has it's view model which has no logic at all but rather forwards everything to the "view model" it has been passed during navigation. The `ViewModelLocator` remains unchanged, and you code the forwarding (intermediate) view model (that is bound to the page).

Comment: Ah, so for this approach I could implement some kind of `CopyTo` method, which copies the data of one view model instance to another. Is that what you meant?

Comment: I meant to keep the passed view model in a field and redirect all properties and commands there, e.g. `public string Name { get => _inner.Name; set => _inner.Name = value; }`

Comment: Okay, so with this approach I would "wrap" the passed view model. But in this case I would have a PickLineViewModel that I use in the `ObservableCollection` of the PickLinePage and one that I bind to the PickLinePage.
Considering this I think the approach that @Dan S. described in his answer would fit better.